# Problem while installing openvpn

Tags: openvpn

I was trying to install openvpn and guess what... An fatal error. I don't know I tried to change /etc/resolv.conf nameservers to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but nothing happend

Here photo of error:
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QmbG.png

Comment: Please do not post text as pictures. Copy from the terminal, and paste into the question. Please see https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format command output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be root to create interfaces.

Try

```
sudo openvpn --config ...
```

Comment: @Emilijus052 then you should accept the answer :)

Comment: how to do that? I am new here

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)